Riot API for Match ID, successful request but no info is retrieved
I'm doing a personal project inspired from u gg, right now I'm working with retrieving match id to get match history. Every time I request, it says it is successful or 200 as status code, but whenever I print it, it displays [ ] only, meaning it is empty.
import requests
import urllib.parse

class Match_History():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    regional_routing_values = ["americas", "europe", "asia"]

    api_key = "I hid my api key."

    game_name = input("\nEnter your Game Name\t: ").strip()
    tagline = input("Enter your Tagline\t: #").strip()

    headers = {"X-Riot-Token": api_key}

    for region in regional_routing_values:
        global_account_url = f"https://{region}.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/{game_name}/{tagline}"
        global_account_response = requests.get(global_account_url, headers = headers)
        global_account_data     = global_account_response.json()
        global_account_status   = global_account_data.get('status', {})
        global_account_message  = global_account_status.get('message', {})

    puuid = global_account_data.get('puuid', None)

    if global_account_response.status_code != 200:
        print()
        print(f"Summoner \"{game_name} #{tagline}\" does not exist globally.")
        print()

        for region in regional_routing_values:
            #prints the error status code to help diagnose issues
            print(f"Region\t: {region}")
            print(f"Error\t: {global_account_response.status_code}")
            print(f"\t  - {global_account_message}")
            print()
    else:
        print()
        print(f"Summoner \"{game_name} #{tagline}\" exists globally.")
        print()
        print(f"Puuid : {puuid}")
        print()
        for region in regional_routing_values:
            matches_url = f"https://{region}.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/{puuid}/ids?start=0&count=5"
            matches_response = requests.get(matches_url, headers = headers)
            matches_data = matches_response.json()        

            print(f"Region\t : {region}")
            print(f"Match Id : {matches_data}")
            print()

I tried to check the content using debugger in vs code, the "text" is equivalent which is [ ] too. I'm stuck here as I don't know what to do. I assure you that I used latest api key. What could be my error?
